# How to pass ID to Fetch API so I can perform a DELETE?

Tags: javascript, rest

I have a REST API which is consumed:

```
fetch("/people")
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => {
  data.forEach(item => {
    content += `<div class="card"> <p>${item.PersonName}</p> <a href="JavaScript:void(0);">Delete</a></div>`;
  });
  cardContainer.innerHTML = content;
});
```

The data is fetched from a database behind the scene. The ID of each person is available in `${item.ID}` which is not shown in the example above, but it is available in `${item.ID}` if needed.

I would like to delete a specific person by clicking a link, however I would like to use the FetchAPI for deletion, so I can use the DELETE method. I was thinking on adding an event listener to the `<a>` element but how do I pass the ID so the FetchAPI know which row to delete? Fetch API perform DELETE on `people/n` where `n` is the number.

Of course I can do `<a href="people/n">Delete person</a>` but this way I call the `people/n` handler on the back-end with the GET method and not by using the DELETE method and Fetch API.

Any suggetion is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can set the request method of `fetch` like so:

```
fetch(`/people/${item.ID}`, {
    method: DELETE
});
```

Comment: I don't think you got the idea. I click that anchor link, which doesn't point to any link, but it will have an event listener attached to it that calls some JavaScript code. How does the fetch API inside the event listener know which ID to delete if nothing is passed through the link. The FetchAPI shown above has nothing to do with the Fetch API inside the event listener.

Comment: The most I can do is to add a data field to the link `<a href="JavaScript:void(0); data-personid="theID">` or the target link `data-target="http://example.com/people/person-id/"`